# Is distilled water automatically deionised water?

Tags: distillation, water

In the process of distilling water. Does the said water become de-ionised? I don't know how many ways I've tried to put this but it keeps coming back as not up to your standards. Oh that did it it wasn't verbose enough.

Comment: Does this Wikipedia article help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purified_water?wprov=sfti1

Comment: For what it’s worth, distilled water has far fewer ions, but whether it is deionized depends on your definition of purity.

Comment: Measure the resistance. If it's 18Mohm, it's deionised